# For loop in Ansible Template

Tags: ansible

I have problem!

I'm using for in template file

```
{% for vhost in item %}
server = {{vhost}}
{% endfor %}
```

With items use with_items in file yml ansible

But out out is

```
server = d
server = o
server = m
server = a
server = i
server = n
server = 1
server = .
server = c
server = o
server = m
```

I want have output

```
server = domain1.com
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have created a loop inside a loop. `with_items` in your task is the outer loop. `{% for vhost in item %}` is the inner loop.

The solution is to only have one loop. Try changing your template to:

```
server = {{ item }}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, 
I have a miss take stupid!

I found!

Many thanks!