# Pushing items to a var while looping over another var in Ansible Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Inventory:

```
[Test]
local ansible_host=localhost

[Test:vars]
my_clusters="A,B,C"
```

I'm trying to write a jinja2 template iterating over `my_clusters` var.
Over the web mostly I found below way of iterating (Also here [For loop in Ansible Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430817/for-loop-in-ansible-template)):

```
{% for item in hostvars[groups['Test'][0]]['my_clusters'].split(',') %}
{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

which produces output:

```
A
B
C
```

But my requirement is to print string "Cluster" (comma separated on the same line) as many times the no. of items in `my_clusters` var.
Expected output:

```
Cluster,Cluster,Cluster
```

I tried something like below. But it's not working.

```
{% set str="" %}
{% for cluster in hostvars[groups['Test'][0]]['my_clusters'].split(',') %}
{% str += "Cluster," %}
{% endfor %}
{{str}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with [assignments introduced in Jinja2 2.10](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments):

```
{% set ns = namespace(str="") %}
{% for cluster in hostvars[groups['Test'][0]]['my_clusters'].split(',') %}
{% set ns.str = ns.str + "Cluster" %}
{%- if not loop.last %}{% set ns.str = ns.str + "," %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

The above answers the question from the title, but there are some syntactical problems with your code:

- lack of `set` inside the expression,
- using `+=` operator,
- not handling the last `,`.